# How many numbers have unit digit $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $f(n)$ be the number of positive integers that have exactly $n$ digits and whose
>   digits have a sum of $5$. Determine, with proof, how many of the $2014$ integers
>   $f(1), f(2), . . . , f(2014)$ have a units digit of $1.$

**HINTS ONLY**

**EDIT:**

for $f(2)$ we have: $x + y = 5$ with $x \ne 0$, which gives: $\binom{5}{1}$

$f(5)$ gives: $x + y + z + t +w = 5$ so: $\binom{8}{4}$

$f(4)$ gives, $\binom{7}{3}$

For $f(n)$ we have: $f(n) = \binom{n + 3}{n-1}$

$f(n) = \frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)!}{24(n-1)!} = \frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)(n)}{24}$

**PROOF CHECK:**

> Consider $N = \overline{a_1 a_2 ... a_n}$ with $a_i$ as digits such that $a_1 \ge 1$. We have a string of $n$ characters, $a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n$ with $a_1 \ne 0$, thus this string with $a_n$ gives the $n$th digit numbers. the number of numbers corresponds to the solutions of: $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = 5$ for nonnegative integers with $a_1 > 0$. By the stars-and-bars principle there exist: $\binom{n + 4 - 1}{n-1} = \binom{n+3}{n-1} = \frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)(n)}{24}$ numbers, thus giving an explicit formula for $f(n)$.

*Is this enough for a proof? Or is induction needed for a stronger argument?*

So we have: $f(n) \equiv 1\pmod{10}$.

> Since $f(n)$ is a combinatoric coefficient, $f(n) \in \mathbb{Z+}$, which implies that: $\frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)(n)}{24} \equiv (n+3)(n+2)(n+1)(n) \pmod{10}$. Since the numerator was divisible by the denominator for all $n$.

Now help is needed:

> How to solve this modular arithemetic expression?

Comment: Does $491$ have a digit sum $5$ or $14$? The problem does say "whose digits have sum $5$", which I would interpret as $491$ giving $14$.

Comment: Do you mean with repeated digit sum $5$? Because $950\equiv 5\pmod 9$ but $9+5+0\neq 5$. "Digit sum" to me means $9+5+0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, source: Waterloo Euclid Conest 2014, http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2014/2014EuclidContest.pdf

Comment: @Arthur, source: http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2014/2014EuclidContest.pdf

Comment: Don't make me go someplace else to understand your question. Present your question here completely, please.

Comment: I would interpret that problem as $f(3)$ counting $104$ but not $491$. But that might just be me. When taking the test itself, this is exactly the kind of classifying question you have to ask before attempting the problem. @ThomasAndrews I went there, and the problem is copied correctly (verbatim, or close enough), which means it won't help going to the source. But yes, you are right.

Comment: (Am I supposed to read that whole text to find your question? Help people help you.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, very sorry, that part got cutoff. It is Problem $9b$ at the second last page; sorry about this. The problem is I dont completely understand myself, which is why I am referring to the exact source. I think it is just sum $5$, so $491$ wont count I believe?

Comment: A plain reading of "sum of digits" gives $f(n)=\binom{n+3}{4}$. To be not divisible by $5$, $n\equiv 1\pmod 5$. To not be even, you need $n\equiv 1,2,3,4\pmod 8$. That somewhat restricts the values.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, my function I defined was not correct for some reason. What does divisibility have to do with the solution though? How can i start properly?

Comment: If $M$ ends in $1$, it is not divisible by $2$ or $5$, so divisible is a part of the question for eliminating some values. @Amad27

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I have made a massive update, I am just stuck at the last part?

Comment: No, $\binom{n+3}{4}$ is not congruent to $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$. Just try a single value, $n=1$. Is $1\equiv 24\pmod {10}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve $$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}\equiv 1\pmod{10},$$

You can multiple both sides by $3$, since it is relatively prime to $10$, but when you multiply by $8$, you have to apply that to the modulus, to. So, you are trying to solve:

$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\equiv 24\pmod{80}$$

Solve this in pairs, using Chinese remainder theorem:

$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\equiv 24\pmod{5}$$
$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\equiv 24\pmod{16}$$

As it turns out, the second only depends on $n\pmod 8$.

Comment: (+1)  The separation seems really difficult, is there an easier approach?

Comment: If we have $a/b \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ then could it follow that $a \equiv b \pmod{10}$? If yes then, $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) \equiv 24 \pmod{10} \equiv 4 \pmod{10}$. Then, $n = 10k + 4$ or $n = 10k + 3, n = 10k + 2, n = 10k + 1$. The ones gives: $\{201.4, 201.1, 201.2, 201.3  \}$ as the numbers for the number of $k$ values. Then check: $k=0$: works. Thus, from $k=0 \to 201$ gives: $201 - 0 + 1 = 202$ values of $k$, thus $202$ values of $n$? Is this justified?

Comment: But the reverse is not true - if $b$ divides $a$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{10}$ it is not necessarily true that $a/b\equiv 1\pmod{10}$. Take, for example, $a=15,b=5$ or $a=12,b=2$.  Solving $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\equiv 24\pmod{10}$ will give you false answers. For example, $n=6$ is a root of the $\equiv 24\pmod{10}$ equation, but not the original.

Comment: Okay. So, how did you separate it into $\equiv 24 \pmod{80}$?

Comment: You keep using that word "separate." Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: All I am asking is: How did you go from $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/24 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ to $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) \equiv 24 \pmod{80}$?